# jQuery on resize only update variable depending on browser width

Tags: jquery, variables, resize

I've had a good look but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I have a starting var of var dsize = 6 and would like this value to change between various browser widths on resize. For all that responsive stuff you know.

The problem I face is that I only want to update the var and not the whole chunk of code that follows for performance.

```
$(window).on('load resize',function (){
var dsize = 6;
var wrapper = $('.clients-spec');
var ul;
if ($(window).width() >= 1200) {
    var dsize = 6;
}
if ($(window).width() < 1200) {
    var dsize = 5;
}
if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
    var dsize = 4;
}
if ($(window).width() < 800) {
    var dsize = 3;
}
if ($(window).width() < 600) {
    var dsize = 2;
}...code...});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k7Wrn/

My deepest apologies if this is much simpler than I am making it, or has been asked multiple times and please point me in the right direction.

Cheers.

Comment: the code snippet you have here seems to work. what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Just `return` if any of the conditions are triggered

Comment: Also use if/else if/else not only if. And when you talk about Performance: don't use $(window).width() several times for a comparison. Better: use it once and store the result in variable that you can compare afterwards as often as you want. Remember the difference between querying a variable and the execution of a function. And in this case you even call two functions $() and width(). Just a suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a function that return `dsize` on resize according to browser width

```
$(function (){

    function get_dsize(elem)
    {
         var dsize=0;

         if (elem.width() >= 1200) dsize = "6";           
         if (elem.width() < 1200)  dsize = "5";          
         if (elem.width() < 1000)  dsize = "4";
         if (elem.width() < 800)   dsize = "3";
         if (elem.width() < 600)   dsize = "2";

        return dsize;
   }

     $(window).on("resize", function() {
       var size = get_dsize($(this));
        $('p').html(size);
    });

});
```

If you are looking for Responsiveness , that can be achieved through CSS `media-queries`:
Eg:

```
@media screen and (max-width: max_width) and (min-width: min_width)
    {
        .yourclassname{
            //css
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code, register an `resize` event handler. Also, you only need to specify dsize as variable once at the top, you can leave the `var` keyword after that.

Anyway, here is a fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k7Wrn/1/

Code:

```
$(function (){
    var dsize = "6";
    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        if ($(this).width() >= 1200) {
            dsize = "6";
        }
        if ($(this).width() < 1200) {
            dsize = "5";
        }
        if ($(this).width() < 1000) {
            dsize = "4";
        }
        if ($(this).width() < 800) {
            dsize = "3";
        }
        if ($(this).width() < 600) {
            dsize = "2";
        }
        $('p').html(dsize);
    });
    $('p').html(dsize);
});
```

Generally speaking the "responsive stuff" is done through css with media queries though.

Comment: Cheers for the response

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
  var dsize = "6";
  $(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1200) {
        var dsize = "6";
    }
    if ($(window).width() < 1200) {
        var dsize = "5";
    }
    if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
        var dsize = "4";
    }
    if ($(window).width() < 800) {
        var dsize = "3";
    }
    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
        var dsize = "2";
    }
    $('p').html(dsize);
  }).resize();  //<---------add this to calculate on page load itself
});
```

#### [Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7Wrn/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the response Jai.